# An inequality in $L^p$ spaces: $\|f\|_q\leq M^{(\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{p})}\|f\|_p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal B, \mu)$ be a measure space, and $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb C$ a measurable function. Suppose $M:=\sup\left\{\mu(A)\mid 0<\mu(A)<\infty\right\}<\infty$. Show that for $0<q<p<\infty$ we have
>   $$\|f\|_q\leq M^{(\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{p})}\|f\|_p$$

---

Any hints please?

Chebyshev's inequality does not seem to help here.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{q}p>1$  then the map $\phi: x\mapsto x^{\frac{q}p}$ is convex and therefore by Jenssens inequality(which is convexity)  we have

$$\phi\left(\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X|f|^p d\mu\right)\le \frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X\phi\circ|f |^pd\mu $$
 that is 
$$\left(\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X|f|^p d\mu\right)^{q/p}\le \frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X|f |^qd\mu $$

that is $$\|f\|_p\leq\|f\|_q\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}$$